# Why doesn't dojo.io.script.get() execute the provided error function when receiving a 404?

Tags: dojo, cross-domain

I am trying to use the following to do a cross-domain get:

```js
dojo.io.script.get({
  url: myUrl,
  callbackParamName: "callback",
  preventCache: true,
  load: dojo.hitch( this, loadFunction ),
  error: dojo.hitch( this, function() {
    console.log('Error!!!');
  })
});
```

The load function runs fine, however, when the server returns a 404, the error function does not run. Can anyone tell me why?

**EDIT**

After some investigation, I found that a timeout and handler could be implemented in the following way:

```js
dojo.io.script.get({
  url: myUrl,
  callbackParamName: "callback",
  timeout: 2000
}).then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
}, function(error){
  alert(error);
});
```

This uses functionality provided by the `dojo.Deferred` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing server with script tags (that what `dojo.io.script.get` does), status code and headers are not available.

You may try some other ways to detect a problem, like using a timeout and analyzing a content of a script. The latter is problematic for JSONP calls (like in your example).

Comment: Thanks, Eugene. I don't have a lot of experience with dojo, and I never ran into this using the jsonp plugin for jQuery, so this took me by surprise.I guess that plugin must have a check like you suggest - I will have to take a closer look at that code.

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is old but I thought I'd share a solution in case others, like I had, come across this thread.*

`dojo.io.script` is essentially adding a `<script/>` to your html page.  So you can try this:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', myUrl);
    script.onerror = function() {
        debugger
    }
    script.onload = function() {
        debugger
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

That way if the script fails to load the `onerror` event is called.

*This may not work in every instance but is a good start